# Sort List in Python using user defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, user-defined-functions

```
sortedL1ist = [2343, 323, 34254, 49, 595]

arr = [2343, 323, 34254, 49, 595]
Like in c++ **:** sort(arr,arr+n,AB)

AB(int x, int y)
{
return (x%10)<(y%10) 
}
```

How, can this concept implement in python in sorting list like according unit place digit?

Comment: Not everyone who knows Python knows C++. Please can you explain your logic and give expected output, including a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

you can define what the key to sort by as a lambda function like

```
some_list = [2343, 323, 34254, 49, 595]
sorted_list = sorted(some_list, key=lambda x : x%10)
print(sorted_list)
```

output

```
[2343, 323, 34254, 595, 49]
```

you can go by an old approach using compare method like this

```
def custom_compare(x, y):
    return x%10 - y%10

print(sorted(some_list, cmp=custom_compare))
```

this will give you the same output

**Note** this will work only on python 2.x versions and the `key` is the new and better approach from python 3.x